# How pass "reason" when we use the HTTPException with FASTAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, httpexception

I have an API based on FAST API that, when something goes wrong raises the following exception.

```
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="There is no file to created a zip package. Check device name.")
```

As you can see I included the detail field, however, observing the logs I see the following

```
[2023-12-15 00:16:30,954]:[DEBUG]:[file_operations]:download_log_file() error: 404 reason:Not Found
```

Why the reason is "Not Found" ? Is there anything wrong with the code? The code that captures this log is based on request as you see below:

```
 try:
            r = self.get(
                self.base_url + "/downloadlog",
                headers=headers,
                params=params,
                timeout=100,
            ) 
            
              # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                   ...
                   ...
            else:
                
                print(f"download_log_file() error: {r.status_code} reason:{r.reason}")

                error_response = {
                    "error": f"HTTP error occurred: {r.status_code} {r.reason}",
                    "request_id": request_id,
                }
                raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=r.status_code, detail=error_response
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand how FastAPI handles HTTPException, the reason why you're observing `Not found` message your logger is because FastAPI takes the status code you sent by parameter, search for the error definition using `http` library (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html for further information) and logging it

The detail you are specifying is sent directly to the client as you can see in the documentation of FastAPI:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#import-httpexception (link to the exact section where this is explained better)

Answer (score 0):

You can print more detailed information about Exceptions by setting `exception handlers`:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.exception_handlers import (
    http_exception_handler,
    request_validation_exception_handler,
)
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException


app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def custom_http_exception_handler(request, exc: StarletteHTTPException):
    print(f"{exc.__class__.__name__}: {repr(exc.detail)}")
    return await http_exception_handler(request, exc)


@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    print(f"Request validation error: {exc}")
    return await request_validation_exception_handler(request, exc)

@app.get("/")
def index():
    HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Details...")
```

I think it's also possible to override FastAPI logger's message format, but I didn't manage to figure out how to do it.